# Rewrite all params requests to index.php with Nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

i've URL like this
http://www.example.com/index.php?page=profile&id=324&opt=edit&cat=23&...

I wish I had
http://www.example.com/profile/324/edit/23...

I read several tutorials on how to remove php extension but do not know how to pass other parameters

Thanks to everyone

**UPDATE**

Sovled with PHP solution.

nginx:

```
location / { 
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php; 
}
```

PHP:

```
$params = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

and use them

Answer (score -1):

Actually it's pretty easy if those params are always in the same order as your example.

Add a rewrite rule in your nginx config.

`rewrite ^/index.php?page=(.*)&id=(.*)&opt=(.*)&cat=(.*)(&.*)$ /$1/$2/$3/$4`

But if the order of params changes in every request, we may need another solution.

**UPDATE**
nginx stores request args in variables like $arg_name, the name after $arg_ if the actual request param name. So you just need to rewrite requests to index.php with a tailing question mark to url style you want.

`rewrite ^/index.php? /$arg_page/$arg_id/$arg_opt/$arg_cat;`

Comment: thanks for the reply
unfortunately the order and the parameters may change in every request

Comment: @Arkantolo What's in your index.php? it could be done much more easily with PHP. I think there's no native nginx solution unless you use modules like nginx_lua_module. But it will be way more complicated.

Comment: @Arkantolo There might be a native nginx solution, i'll test on my site first.

Comment: @Arkantolo use ``rewrite ^/index.php? /$arg_page/$arg_id/$arg_opt/$arg_cat;``, I tested on my server, this could work.

Comment: Sovled with PHP solution.

nginx:
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

PHP:
$params = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
and use them

Comment: @Arkantolo After finding the nginx way to do that, I think it is more elegant than using PHP.